# Python Input Without Spaces

Tags: python, input

I am currently learning python and I am trying to create a program that would allow a user to input their "change" and get a total. Personally I have been running it from the command line to test it as I go, but I'm having trouble getting it to respond the way I need it to.

Into the command line I put something like: filename.py 25 10 5 1

But the issue I'm having is that instead of accepting the numbers in the same line, I'm having to do something like:

```
filename.py
25
10
5
1
and then I'll get the total
```

What I want is:

```
filename.py 25 10 5 1
total
```

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
def coin_value(quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies):
     firsttotal = .25 * quarters + .10 * dimes + .05 * nickels + .01 * pennies
     total = round(firsttotal,2)
     currency_string = "${:,.2f}".format(firsttotal)
     print(f"The total value of your change is", currency_string)
coin_value(int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input()))
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually want to prompt them *after* the program is launched? Seems like you want to pass command line arguments, rather than reading anything after launch. `sys.argv` gives you basic access, but the `argparse` module (e.g. defining four positional arguments with `type=int`) is better for writing customizable, maintainable command line parsing (and it generates your usage messages for you).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike others languages like C or C++ where you can specify what will you read from the terminal with scanf, the input function in python reads a whole line of text instead of just one element.
So the first time that you execute int(input()) you would be reading "25 10 5 1" as a string, and then it would try to parse it as int, that would give you an error.

If you want to send the 4 values in one line I suggest the following:

`quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies = map(int, input().split())`

This would give you 4 variables with the information as an int in a single line.

Edit: I read the other comments and if you want to pass the values as command line arguments you want to use sys.argv:

```
import sys
quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies = map(int, sys.argv[1:])
```

Import sys first.

Answer (score 0):

you may be just need parse the parameter from command line;
if you only want use input function, just modify a little like below:

```
def coin_value(quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies):
     firsttotal = .25 * quarters + .10 * dimes + .05 * nickels + .01 * pennies
     total = round(firsttotal,2)
     currency_string = "${:,.2f}".format(firsttotal)
     print(f"The total value of your change is", currency_string)

input_string = input()
quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies = input_string.split()
coin_value(int(quarters), int(dimes), int(nickels), int(pennies))
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's still making me do filename.py, new line, then the numbers. I am needing it to accept filename.py with the input numbers in the same line.

Comment: you just need sys.argv to parse the parameter ;input function will lauch a new line accept your input

Answer (score 0):

`input` will be called after you launch your program and wait for your input. As per the requirement which you have, `sys.argv` is the way to go.
Try out this:

```
import sys
def coin_value(quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies):
     firsttotal = .25 * quarters + .10 * dimes + .05 * nickels + .01 * pennies
     total = round(firsttotal,2)
     currency_string = "${:,.2f}".format(firsttotal)
     print(f"The total value of your change is", currency_string)

quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies = sys.argv[1:]
coin_value(int(quarters), int(dimes), int(nickels), int(pennies))
```